# How Can I Escape the NBSP (&nbsp;) in Message Board

Tags: escaping, render, html-entities

I write on a message board that displays the `&nbsp;` as a space (rightly so).  But occasionally I want to actually write the NBSP as `&nbsp;` without it being rendered as a space.  Is there a way to escape this so that it can be written?

NOTE:  Seems like a reasonable question - wonder why I got marked down for it?

Comment: That already sounds like a problem, if "raw" text is being pumped out ... XSS anyone?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`&amp;` displays `&`, so you can just write `&amp;nbsp;`.